# Vite esbuild failing for old Non-ESM package

Tags: reactjs, glsl, es6-modules, vite

I'm trying to use `glsl-transpiler`(https://github.com/stackgl/glsl-transpiler) with my vite project but am running into issues with `esbuild`, which outputs

`[ERROR] [plugin vite:dep-pre-bundle] Failed to resolve entry for package "escaper". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.`

Adding `optimizeDeps: {exclude:['glsl-transpiler']}` to `defineConfig` in `vite.config.js` allows the app to build, but I get a `require is not defined` error when I try to use the package due to the https://github.com/stackgl/glsl-transpiler/blob/master/index.js `ll:8`.

Does anyone know how I can successfully use this old package and its old dependencies in my project?

Comment: Related vite issue? -- https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/6859